# Convert Text file with 2 Columns to Excel file using Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

I have a Text file with 2 Columns ( Ip Address and Status of it [Up or Down] )

I would like to use the Powershell script to send it to an excel file that will have 2 Columns and the rows as much IP Address I have.

**From this:**

[image: From this]

**To THIS**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct in thinking your columns in the text file are separated by a space character, you can simply do this:

```
Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\111.txt' -Delimiter ' ' -Header 'IP', 'Status' | 
Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\IpStatus.csv' -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```

<sup>P.S. Please do not add images of code/text in a question. Instead add this info as [Formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)</sup>

---

Although not really sure, from your comment I gather you want to save only items where the Status field is `up`. This can be done really easy by adding a `Where-Object` clause:

```
Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\111.txt' -Delimiter ' ' -Header 'IP', 'Status' | 
Where-Object { $_.Status -eq 'up' } |
Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\IpStatus_Up.csv' -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```

(for items that have Status `down`, change `up` to `down` in the Where-Object, OR change the comparison operator from `-eq` to `ne`)

Comment: Man you are A magician , Thank you very much!
Do you know if i can do something like this ? 

https://ibb.co/PrdR14H

Comment: @AngusY If you are happy with the answer please accept it (click on the tick next to the answer)